# Как изменить положение маркера (Google Maps)

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

По стандарту всегда указательная точка стоит внизу по центру.
Как сделать, чтоб эта точка была внизу слева?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно вам надо просто подставить свою иконку вместо стандартного маркера?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня другая иконка с другим указателем, сам указатель находится снизу слева.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю суть вашей проблемы, но вот в доках какой-то anchor есть - попробуйте его применить: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float, float)